# Linker error : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol

Tags: c++, visual-c++, mfc, linker

I'm new to C++ and have encountered a problem while running my app. I googled the problem but since most results were with linking libraries I started a new thread.

I have a class CResizableDialog which I'm inheriting from my VtkDialogTest2 dialog class.

VtkDialogTest2.h;

```
#pragma once

#include "CResizableDialog.h"


#ifdef _WIN32_WCE
#error "CDHtmlDialog is not supported for Windows CE."
#endif 

// VtkDialogTest2 dialog

class VtkDialogTest2 : public CResizableDialog
{
    DECLARE_DYNCREATE(VtkDialogTest2)

public:
    VtkDialogTest2(CWnd* pParent = NULL);   // standard constructor
    virtual ~VtkDialogTest2();
// Overrides
    HRESULT OnButtonOK(IHTMLElement *pElement);
    HRESULT OnButtonCancel(IHTMLElement *pElement);





// Dialog Data
    enum { IDD = IDD_DIALOG4 };

protected:
    virtual void DoDataExchange(CDataExchange* pDX);    // DDX/DDV support
    virtual BOOL OnInitDialog();

    DECLARE_MESSAGE_MAP()

public:
    afx_msg void OnBnClickedOk();
};
```

VtkDialogTest2.cpp

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "Geometry.h"
#include "VtkDialogTest2.h"


IMPLEMENT_DYNCREATE(VtkDialogTest2, CResizableDialog)

VtkDialogTest2::VtkDialogTest2(CWnd* pParent /*=NULL*/)
    : CResizableDialog(VtkDialogTest2::IDD, pParent),
{

}

VtkDialogTest2::~VtkDialogTest2()
{
}

void VtkDialogTest2::DoDataExchange(CDataExchange* pDX)
{
    CResizableDialog::DoDataExchange(pDX);
}



BOOL VtkDialogTest2::OnInitDialog()
{
    CResizableDialog::OnInitDialog();
    //some code


    return TRUE;  // return TRUE  unless you set the focus to a control
}

BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(VtkDialogTest2, CResizableDialog)
    ON_BN_CLICKED(IDOK, &VtkDialogTest2::OnBnClickedOk)
END_MESSAGE_MAP()

//some code
```

I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong. I downloaded an example from the web which uses the CResizableDialog.h class the exact same way and copied both CResizableDialog.h and CResizableDialog.cpp into my project.

The errors I'm getting are;

```
1>VtkDialogTest2.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: __thiscall CResizableDialog::CResizableDialog(unsigned int,class CWnd *)" (??0CResizableDialog@@QAE@IPAVCWnd@@@Z) referenced in function "public: __thiscall VtkDialogTest2::VtkDialogTest2(class CWnd *)" (??0VtkDialogTest2@@QAE@PAVCWnd@@@Z)
1>VtkDialogTest2.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "protected: virtual int __thiscall CResizableDialog::OnInitDialog(void)" (?OnInitDialog@CResizableDialog@@MAEHXZ) referenced in function "protected: virtual int __thiscall VtkDialogTest2::OnInitDialog(void)" (?OnInitDialog@VtkDialogTest2@@MAEHXZ)
1>VtkDialogTest2.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "protected: static struct AFX_MSGMAP const * __stdcall CResizableDialog::GetThisMessageMap(void)" (?GetThisMessageMap@CResizableDialog@@KGPBUAFX_MSGMAP@@XZ)
1>C:\Users\Geometry.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 3 unresolved externals
```

Any input will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Do you implement those methods in some cpp file and compile/link the file?

Comment: The implementation of `CResizableDialog` seems to be missing.

Answer (score 1):

The error was because I copied the CResizableDialog.h and CResizableDialog.cpp files directly into the project folder. I later noticed that they didn't show up in the solution window and copied them to the window as well. After that the errors disappeared.

Comment: You can't just copy files into a folder and hope the IDE will pick them up, you have to tell the IDE to actually use the files by adding them to the project. There are hundreds, if not thousands of duplicates of this exact problem here on SO.